Elasticsearch add synonym at index time based on token content
What I'm trying to do is to have words in french language indexed in multiple forms as synonyms. For example l'ami to be indexed as is plus two synonyms: "lami" and "l ami" so my synonym graph for this word would look something like:
---l---ami--
|          |
---l'ami----
|          |
---lami-----

One could use the Conditional token filter to check if an apostrophe (I'll normalize all apostrophe types with a char filter beforehand) is present in the word and apply a synonym or some kind of filter if this is the case.
Is there a way to dynamically add synonyms at index/query time based on the condition that a certain char is found in the string ?

If I understand your question clearly, you can use char_filter . In that way, you can convert ``` to space or remove it and keep the all three options in different fields. During search you can search all three fields to find the best match.
It'll happen at the index time and you can index whole data instead of using synonym table.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html

Your solution is the multiplexer filter. It let filter tokens in various manner
Mapping with your the condition filter and multiplexer
PUT /dynamic_synonyms
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "dynamic_synonym_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "elision_detect_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "dynamic_synonym_filter": {
                    "type": "multiplexer",
                    "filters": [
                        "apostroph_remove_filter",
                        "lowercase",
                        "apostroph_space_replace_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "apostroph_space_replace_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "'",
                    "replacement": " "
                },
                "apostroph_remove_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "'",
                    "replacement": ""
                },
                "elision_detect_filter": {
                    "type": "condition",
                    "filter": [
                        "dynamic_synonym_filter"
                    ],
                    "script": {
                        "source": """token.term.toString().startsWith('l\'')"""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The lowercase filter in dynamic_synonym_filter is a noop filter
Analyzing string
POST /dynamic_synonyms/_analyze
{
    "analyzer" : "dynamic_synonym_analyzer",
    "text" : "l'ami bon"
}

Response
{
    "tokens" : [
        {
            "token" : "l'ami",
            "start_offset" : 0,
            "end_offset" : 5,
            "type" : "word",
            "position" : 0
        },
        {
            "token" : "lami",
            "start_offset" : 0,
            "end_offset" : 5,
            "type" : "word",
            "position" : 0
        },
        {
            "token" : "l ami",
            "start_offset" : 0,
            "end_offset" : 5,
            "type" : "word",
            "position" : 0
        },
        {
            "token" : "bon",
            "start_offset" : 6,
            "end_offset" : 9,
            "type" : "word",
            "position" : 1
        }
    ]
}


I found also the answer of @G0l0s a perfect and suitable in your case. We would like to add, optionally, you may also want to use the default approach using elision token filter. For example, you can do the following:
PUT /the_mini_force
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "elision_case_insensitive" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "elision_case_insensitive": {
          "type": "elision",
          "articles": [ "l"],
          "articles_case": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


The result would just be:
POST /the_mini_force/_analyze
{
    "text" : "l'ami bon"
}

Response:
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "ami",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "bon",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}


